# Moving divs in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have problem with changing div's position. I want to move one div above another. This is my html:

```
<div class="box">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

In this example div 3 must be above div 2. I found some examples with jQuery, but i need only with Java Script. Is it possible?

Comment: Consider using CSS instead? If you want to change the order using JS, why not use [`Element.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)?

Comment: What problem do you have? What have you tried to achieve the result?

Comment: Thanks you very much! It worked :)